# Unable to launch notebook in new notebook editor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

The may 2021 update for VSCode is supposed to include the finalized native notebook editor, allowing for the use of the updated editor that has been in VSCode Insider for a while. When I go to open an existing .ipynb file, or create a new blank workbook, it opens in the "old" editor (the one without the bells and whistles like cell runtime and better intellisense).

My coworker got it to work just fine. I've tried a fresh install (not just uninstall from the control panel, but also deleting the files in appdata, etc.).

VSCode Version: 1.57
Jupyter Extension Version: v2021.6.999406279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on the VS Code Jupyter extension. Currently we are just rolling out the new UI to a limited number of stable users. Your co-worker is probably just in the random selection for the new interface. The only guarantee right now to get the new UI is to continue to use Insiders.

Edit: You can also try opting into this experience using the following setting:

```
    "jupyter.experiments.optInto": ["__NativeNotebookEditor__"],
```

In your vscode settings. Note that you may need to delete workbench.editorAssociations from settings when entering or leaving the native experiment manually.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the information Ian.

Comment: Actually I just added a edit to my comment. There is a setting you can try quick in stable that should opt you into the native experiment. Should mean that you don't have to download insiders to check this out.